# GC Tenuring threshold falls down in few minutes after app starts

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

REST APP(that only retrieves data from MongoDB and returns it in JSON format) displays in GC logs that tenuring threshold falls to 1 in few minutes after it starts.

As I understand it means that objects get promoted into Old Gen after first minor GC(without coming to Survivor Space).

In my opinion such case may happen in Survivor Space is not big enough, but I tried to increase it as much as I have resources and it didn't help.

Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

JVM parameters:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms10g -Xmx10g -Xmn9g -XX:SurvivorRatio=1 -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

The same result without happends without increasing survivor ration and young space too.

Applied GC(From JConsole VM Summary)**[Edit]**:

- PS MarkSweep for Old Gen
- PS Scavenge for Young Gen

GC logs:

```
    27.066: [GC
Desired survivor size -1073741824 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 3145728K->356400K(6291456K)] 3145728K->356560K(7340032K), 0.3177926 secs] [Times: user=0.42 sys=0.05, real=0.32 secs] 
36.507: [GC
Desired survivor size -1073741824 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 3502128K->382760K(6291456K)] 3502288K->382928K(7340032K), 0.2196291 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.01, real=0.22 secs] 
77.584: [GC
Desired survivor size -1073741824 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 3528488K->148479K(6291456K)] 3528656K->148655K(7340032K), 0.0672362 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
86.079: [GC
Desired survivor size -1073741824 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 3294207K->129156K(6291456K)] 3294383K->129340K(7340032K), 0.0599233 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
92.699: [GC
Desired survivor size 472383488 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 3274884K->129472K(6291456K)] 3275068K->129664K(7340032K), 0.0523734 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
101.012: [GC
Desired survivor size 459276288 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 3275200K->130300K(8988672K)] 3275392K->130500K(10037248K), 0.0669330 secs] [Times: user=0.22 sys=0.05, real=0.07 secs] 
125.649: [GC
Desired survivor size 454557696 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 8657660K->85345K(8975872K)] 8657860K->173403K(10024448K), 0.6692181 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.19, real=0.67 secs] 
148.465: [GC
Desired survivor size 462422016 bytes, new threshold 3 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 8612705K->6344K(8977920K)] 8700763K->132249K(10026496K), 0.0723653 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.06, real=0.07 secs] 
178.740: [GC
Desired survivor size 462422016 bytes, new threshold 2 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 8540360K->6658K(8985600K)] 8666265K->132919K(10034176K), 0.0336259 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
213.928: [GC
Desired survivor size 457703424 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 8540674K->6018K(8990208K)] 8666935K->133350K(10038784K), 0.0146560 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Any ideas regarding the ways to solve this issue or documents regarding tenuring threshold auto adjustment will be highly appeciated.

Comment: What GC do you use, Parallel or CMS? `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` will show it if you're unaware. And what is your aim here, higher throughput or lower latency?

Comment: @AndrewLygin, I added GC in the question, please see updates. I think to do some experiments with CMS GC in Old Gen after I find out cause of low tenuring threshold(So, low latency is quite importnat for me)

Comment: CMS is always aiming to reduce latency, i. e. make the GC pauses shorter. That might include reducing the threshold in order not to move data from place to place every time. CMS is quite sophisticated per se and can do a great job in reducing the pauses by gradually adjusting to your program behaviour. As you can see, the last GC only took 0.014 sec in comparison with 0.317 at the very beginning. So, sometimes it's better to just let it make its job and not meddle to much.

Comment: I think `SurvivalRatio=1` is a bad choice. It's better to set options like `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=?` (if you want to make pauses shorter) or  `-XX:GCTimeRatio=?` if you want to increase throughput, and let GC make all the automatic adjustments. In most cases this is the best option.

Comment: @AndrewLygin, I the moment I want to focus on the theoretical issue about low tenuring theshold. The problem is that too many objects get promoted to the Old Gen and it's not very good. I tried to run application without SurvivalRatio=1 flag but tenuring threshold very low again(eq 1). I couldn't find any documents regarding tenuring threshold auto adjustment algorithm.

Comment: What make you think that those objects are going to the Old Gen? Have you profiled the memory somehow? It might occur that all the objects from the Survival space are just collected by the next GC.

Comment: @AndrewLygin, as I understand tenuring threshold=1 means that objects get promoted to the Old Gen after first minor GC. There are always some objects which are used when GC comes, so they get promoted to old Gen. However they could be removed during next minor GC . Please correct me if I miss something

Comment: threshold=1 means that objects are promoted after surviving two GCs (one in the Eden and one in the Survival space).

Comment: Oh, I see, that for this point. I see that objects keep coming to the Old Gen from Jconsole Old Gen pool. Almost each minor GC pushes some objects to the Olg Gen.

Comment: I would say that your GC log is pretty good. If you had some Old Gen promotion problems you would see the fifth number growing. But it's quite stable which make me think nothing goes to your Old Gen. Your objects are dying either in Eden after the first GC or in the Survival after the second. You can easily confirm that by means of jconsole or visualvm.

Comment: this is old gen chart: https://postimg.org/image/gq7fi5mi9/

Comment: Hmm, thats odd and doesn't fit the log data. In this case I agree, the solution would be to make objects sit longer in the Survival. But it's only valid if you're absolutely sure that this is not a memory leak.

Comment: The log that I attached only shows information about application startup and few minutes after it. JConsole chart shows much more time range. Yeah, I'm absolutely sure that it's not a memory leak because Full GC clean up almost whole Old Gen. Do you have any ideas how I can keep objects in Survival space longer?

Comment: Do you care more about pauses or througput? I would try ParallelGC as an option. It doesn't care about reducing pauses as much as CMS does and its strategy on GC adjustments differs.

Comment: As another option you might tell CMS to care less about pauses by setting `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300` (or even higher) for instance. Then it might decide to not promote objects as they don't prevent it from reaching the pause goal you set.

Comment: In fact, PS MarkSweep and PS Scavenge are parallel collectors. You may take a look here: http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml

Comment: At the moment I don't care a lot about pauses or thoughput. I just want to figure out why threshold is so low

Comment: Yeah, they are both parallel (actually, I wrote some articles on collectors myself, you might find something useful in them: https://habrahabr.ru/post/269621/), but they are dealing with different problems. ParallelGC is designed to improve throughput, CMS is for reducing pauses.

Comment: I think it's so low because it helps CMS keep GC pauses low. And that's the main goal CMS is always trying to achieve, it was designed to do that.

Comment: Thanks for articles, they should be extremely useful for me. Why do you think that CMS GC is running? JConsole shows that it's parallel

Comment: Because you mentioned MarkSweep in your comment. MS in CMS stands for MarkSweep. But you can easily check that by adding `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` option and analyzing stdout. Look for flags UseSerialGC and UseConcMarkSweepGC. One of them will be switched on.

Comment: bool UseConcMarkSweepGC = false, UseSerialGC = false

Comment: There might be one more problem that prevents GC from cleaning your memory quickly -- finalizers. If your objects are short-living they must be dead after the second GC since intervals between GCs is quite long (longer than the response time of your sever, I guess). But finalizers make objects live one GC longer, which might bring them right to the Old Gen in your case.

Comment: I assume that even if there are many finalizers JVM should try to clean them after multiple minor GC. In my case it even doesn't try, as tenuring threshold is low

Comment: Please, check UseG1GC flag.

Comment: bool UseG1GC                                   = false

Comment: The only option left is UseSerialGC. But that would be too odd. Please, check it.

Comment: UseSerialGC                               = false

Comment: bool UseParallelGC                            := true

Comment: I see, I just misread your comment with CMS and Serial, my fault.

Comment: Have you tried setting `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300`? If yes, what was the effect?

Comment: I'm trying it right now, unfortunately no effect

Comment: You could also try switch off `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`. This option is responsible for making the collector 'smart'. It works for automatic generations sizing but I'm not sure about the promoting threshold. Maybe when switched off it also prevents collector from automatic adjusting of this parameter.

Comment: But it's better to not use `SurvivorRatio=1` (it's too huge) with `-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`.

Comment: I see that UseAdaptiveSizePolicy is enabled by default

Comment: Yes, and I suggest to disable it -- to put the minus before the option name: `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`.

Comment: Oh, I've got it. I disabled this flag but it stopped writing tenuring distribution logs, so I can't check the threshold

Comment: But you still can get an overview of what's going on in jconsole. Is it something new there?

Comment: Right now it looks much more better. I want to wait some time and check logs with range at least of 1 hour. Also I obtained tenuring threshold with jstat -gcnew command

Comment: Also it sounds weird for me that default adaptative policy causes such problems

Comment: What are GC pauses now? Are they longer? Shorter? The same?

Comment: And what is the value of threshold now? Is it static?

Comment: At the moment I can't compare exact numbers as I documented previous results. GC pauses looks not bad(up to 150ms in Young Gen, no GC in Old yet). I'll measure the differences a little later

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I didn't mention it. It's 15 now. It looks like it doesn't change

Comment: Finally I ran few tests and got following results 
 with -Xmx5g: 
3.280 seconds on PS MarkSweep (1 collections)
45.107 seconds on PS Scavenge (1,824 collections)
 with -Xmx5g -Xmn3g -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:SurvivorRatio=3
  0.000 seconds on PS MarkSweep (0 collections)
15.869 seconds on PS Scavenge (1,613 collections)
Also promotion rate was about 7-8 times less in the second approach. So, your idea really helped. The only point that I can't understand is that why default JVM behaviour causes such issues. Anyway, thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The real cause of the default GC behaviour is hard to explain, but there're several things worth keeping in mind: a) ParallelGC is designed to increase throughput and since you didn't measure it, you cannot tell that your solution actually works better from this point of view;

Comment: b) You use relatively old VM version, PGC was optimised since 7.40 several times; c) When PGC was first designed, heaps of 1GB and larger were quite rare and it was not optimized to deal with them. To deal with such heaps Oracle introduced G1GC in 7.4 (but it was pretty weak until recently). It would be interesting to compare your results with G1GC on JDK 8.60 and higher.

Comment: And if you have some time and strong desire to find out what really happens inside GC and why it behaves like that, you can have a look: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/gc_implementation. All counters of psGCAdaptivePolicyCounters.cpp are not easy to grasp quickly )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize my thoughts on the issue after our long discussion and experiments:

Your VM chose ParallelGC by default and it's trying to increase throughput by all means. Usually, the collector is quite smart in that, but it's obviously not smart enough to produce best results in all cases. Especially given the fact that your heap is quite large for ParallelGC which was not designed to deal with such memory volumes efficiently. Unfortunately, G1GC that was devised to replace other collectors on large heaps, was pretty weak in your version of VM and is unlikely to produce better results.

If you don't have any real issues with pauses or with throughput, I would not recommend going further than `xmx`, `xmn`, `xms`, `MaxGCPauseMillis` and `GCTimeRatio`, since having objects in Old Gen is not bad per se, it's only bad when full GC causes pauses that don't meet your demands. But if after all considerations you still want to make GC keep tenuring threshold high under any circumstances, you can switch off the collector's 'smartness' by setting `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`. It will prevent automatic tuning and allow you to specify desired region sizes and threshold (`-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=?`) that will not be changed by collector. It's also useful for learning purpose, but be careful with it in production.

Comment: Hm, I was thinking about G1 as a replace for CMS GC, not parallel

Comment: You're right, it was positioned by Oracle as the future "first choice latency collector" instead of CMS, but its ability to handle large heaps also made it a reasonable alternative of ParallelGC under certain circumstances. Moreover, after years of tweaking and polishing it became mature enough and now JEP 248 (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8073273) is  pretty close to replace ParallelGC with G1 as the default collector on server platforms.